# gtkmm3 drawings outside on_draw

Tags: cairo, gtkmm3

I am working on the real-time plot application where a stream of data is to be plotted on screen. Earlier using *gtkmm2* I had done this using a custom widget (derived from `Gtk::Bin`) where I have a member function which creates a cairo context and does the plotting.

Now with *gtkmm3* I am unable to plot in any method other than `on_draw`. Here's what my custom draw method body looks like

```
Gtk::Allocation oAllocation = get_allocation();
Glib::RefPtr <Gdk::Window> refWindow = get_window();
Cairo::RefPtr <Cairo::Context> refContext =
  refWindow->create_cairo_context();

refWindow->begin_paint_rect(oAllocation); //added later

refContext->save();

refContext->reset_clip();

refContext->set_source_rgba(1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1);

refContext->move_to(oAllocation.get_x(),
                    oAllocation.get_y());
refContext->line_to(oAllocation.get_x()
                    + oAllocation.get_width(),
                    oAllocation.get_y()
                    + oAllocation.get_height());
refContext->stroke();

refContext->restore();

refWindow->end_paint();
```

Initially I derived the class from `Gtk::DrawingArea` then tried with `Gtk::Bin` while adding the `begin_paint_rect` call.

Is it forbidden to draw in any place other than `on_draw`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like a plot (or anything that is rather complex to draw) I advise to use a buffer; I lost a month of my life because I read that gtkmm3 does buffering so that using "double buffering" isn't needed anymore (as opposed to gtkmm2), but it aint that simple (read: that isn't true).

So, what you should do is just draw to your own surface; and every time you change something call `queue_draw_region` or `queue_draw_area`.

Then in `on_draw` get the list of clip rectangles and copy those from your private surface to the `cr` that is passed to the `on_draw` function. Cairo normally does
the exact same thing (or so they claim), copying what you just copied again, to the screen; so you should turn that off (this should be possible I read).

The reason you can't use Cairo's buffering is because it doesn't KEEP that buffer; what you get is some corrupted surface, so you are forced to redraw EVERYTHING inside the clip rectangle list. That wouldn't be too bad if you (your application) was the only one making changes (as per your queue_draw_* calls): then you could set a flag, invalidate the part(s) that needs redrawing and simply postpone the draw until you get to `on_draw`. But sometimes `on_draw` is called for other reasons, for example, when you open a menu that goes over your drawing area. I think this is a bug (or a design error) but it is the way it is. The result is that you can't know what you have to redraw EXCEPT by looking at the clip rectangle list; which makes it incredibly hard to just draw a part of your area unless your drawing is made up of many separate rectangles (like, say, a chess board). The only feasible way is to keep a full copy of the image in memory (your private surface) and just copy the clip rectangle list from there when in `on_draw`.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Yes.. this is finally what I have also come to implement. However I am working on an embedded platform with limited memory so I don't keep an ofscreen buffer (like Cairo::ImageSurface). Instead I store the raw waveform data in buffer. Every time I get new data points I queue a region (columns) to be redrawn that is calculated based on the new set of data points. Then in the on_draw function I back calculate the index based on clip rectangles and then draw them out. Indeed it is much more complicated than what I was hoping but it is working fine.

Comment: I agree, having to figure out what elements to draw (as opposed to just copying from a buffer) from the rectangle list is a pain; but it is what I do too now, even for my chess board widget ;). There is an edge around the board that exists of eight different parts too, so I find which parts overlap with the given rectangles and then draw them (so that when two different rectangles overlap the same element I won't draw that element twice!).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it forbidden to draw in any place other than on_draw?

Basically: Yes.

The idea is that you call `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` or `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()` when you want to cause a redraw.

- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw
- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw-area